# Confused about defining interface for client

Tags: java, interface

I am working on defining some system and confused that how API should be designed and provided to external clients.

I will explain a bit about internal system implementation first. There are vehicles managed by system. Vehicles are defined with base class Vehicle and derived classes like Land Vehicles or Air Vehicles. There are some attributes present in Land vehicles which are not required in Air vehicles. Also there could be some attributes in base class like "VehicleType" whose values are controlled by derived class means Land Vehicle can have Car but Ari Vehicle can have type like "Boeing" etc.

I need to provide API to clients for creating/retrieving vehicles. Should I provide interface to client with

1. All attributes in denormalized way such that client won't need
   to care that asset belong to Land or Air derived class ? In creation
   it could be fine but client has to check for it at retrieval at
   least.
2. Should I allow client to directly create Leaf class like LandVehicle
   and pass it to my service ? If that will be case then Client will
   need to query service to find which assetType belongs to which
   derived class.

I believe in 1st approach because client should not bother about system implementation of vehicles and let system decide that which type should be created.

Please provide any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

1. prepare an enum which will contains type of vehicles like land,air etc

   2. prepare a  interface which has all the common properties across all kinds of vehicles.
   3. prepare a class extending the interface and make sure you accept the enum to define the type of vehicle the consumer is requesting.
   4. now using the type of vehicle passed you can create the instance and return the interface.
   5. client and use the enum type and typecast it accordingly and call the specific methods for the class if needed or can use the direct method in interface without typecasting.

Comment: Thanks Sambi for your reply. I understand that you are suggesting to add another ENUM to identify leaf class (Land/Air) and it will help client while using the right leaf class while retrieval. 

But it didn't solve problem of creation. As these ENUM (to identify leaf class) will also depend on vehicle type and which only service knows. 

I assume that you are suggesting second approach here.